# Is there any relation between these two integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose I have a real positive valued continuous function $f(x)$ such that for $\Delta>0$ 
$$\int_0^{\Delta}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1.$$
If I am not provided with any exact functional form of $f(x)$, can I still say something about 
$$I=\int_0^{\Delta}\left[f(x)\right]^2\,\mathrm{d}x$$
i.e., is there any simplification to $I$ given the first equation? I tried integration by parts, but that does not seem to give anything really useful.

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz gives $1 \le I \Delta$.

Comment: (I deleted my answer because I failed to read "positive valued")